# Why can't we put into initializer of T&& a variable of T& or T?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a normative reference describing that fact. I'm trying the following:

```
#include <iostream>
int z = 4;
int &a = z;
int &&b = a; //error: rvalue reference to type 'int' 
             //cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'

int main()
{
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/180014d4417ffa69)**

```
#include <iostream>
int z = 4;
int &a = z;
int &&b = z; //error: error: rvalue reference to type 'int' 
             //cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'

int main()
{
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09e89380683100ef)**

I've read the section 8.3.2 , but couldn't find anything describes that.

Answer (score 4):

8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref] paragraph 5.

The first bullet defines binding lvalues to lvalue references. The second bullet describes other forms of reference initialization which must be for lvalue references to const or rvalue references, and can bind to xvalues, prvalues etc. but not lvalues.

The reasons for disallowing initialization of rvalue references from lvalues are explained in [N2844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2844.html).

Comment: Hmm... okay. I'll read it. Thank you. It would be better if you provided a suitable quote in your answer.

Comment: You also didn't specify a revision number, which would probably be good.

Comment: @MooingDuck, the standard. In any case that reference happens to be the same in the current standard and the previous one so why bother?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Because the reference may not happen to be the same in the _next_ one.

Comment: There's really no need to get angry about it.

Answer (score 2):

One useful intuition to have about rvalue references is that they convey partial 'ownership' of the referred to object -- the object referred to by an rvalue reference won't be accessed any other way, so you can freely modify the object (steal memory that it has allocated is the common case) without 'suprising' anyone else who might be referring to the object some other way.  The whole point of rvalue references is allow for 'move' based semantics where you move around and recycle resources (rather than allocating new resources).

This shows why the above examples are errors.  If you allowed

```
int z;
int &&b = z;
```

then you would have a case where the object referred to by the rvalue reference (b) can still be accessed by some other name (z).  If you want to be able to that, you need to do it explicitly

```
int z;
int &&b = std::move(z);
```

in which case you're saying (effectively) "I don't care about the name 'z' after this point".  The compiler will still track it to clean up any (remaining) resources when it goes out of scope, but the program doesn't care about it or its value.  In the case of an `int` object, there aren't any other resources to steal/move around, so this is all pretty meaningless.  In the case of a complex object like a collection, on the other hand, this can allow for significant performance improvements.

Answer (score -2):

First, you have to move the object to get an rvalue:

```
int &&b = std::move(z);
```

You can think of it like this: if move happens, `z` losts its state and gives it away to `b`.

Comment: Incorrect, `int &&b = z` does not cause `z` to lose any state, and `int c = b;` also does not cause `z` to lose it's state.  There is no possible loss of state in this situation.  So why is it disallowed?

Comment: It's disallowed because this would silently lose state: `void sink(std::unique_ptr<int>); auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(); sink(ptr);`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c9985140bad5d22 Nope: "Error use of deleted function <copy-ctor-for-unique_ptr>".  You'd have to change that to `sink(std::move(ptr));` to make it compile.  The quirk is that `int &&b` is an lvalue, _not_ an rvalue like it pretends.

Comment: @MooingDuck, wtf are you talking about? Of course it doesn't compile, that's my point. If it **did** compile it would lose state. `b` is an lvalue, but because its type is rvalue reference it can only bind to rvalues. The question is about the value category of its initializer, not its own value category.